# Gaps between items only

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need flex items with vertical gaps (10px) between items. Without gaps around.

Solution with `.container {margin: 0 -5px}` is not good, it makes horizontal scrollbar for some reason.

No responsive breakpoints please.

[Code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ddPWKb)

Here is my code without gap:

```css
.container {
  max-width:700px;
  margin:20px auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div > div {
  min-width:300px;
  background:lightblue;
  border:1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin:5px 0px;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
  <div>five</div>
</div>
```

[image: Only inner gaps between flex items]

Comment: This might be straightforward with a media query... is there any reason you don't want to use one?

Comment: Indeed, can **only** be achieved using a media query...not sure why this is an issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D Not entirely true... ;)

Comment: Well a markup change is obviously an answer but I assumed that went without saying. If the OP wont use a media query I ruled out a change in the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish that, w/o using a script or media query, you will need a minor markup change.

With the extra `wrapper` you then compensate the left margin set on the items,
so it will only be visible when wrapped.

*Note, this trick is well known, since more or less all frameworks, like Bootstrap etc., use this to accomplish the same in their solutions. [CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529808/2827823) can do this much simpler, though due to lack of browser support, this is what's mostly used today.*

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQwvjN)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;           /*  added  */
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /*flex-direction:row;           default, not needed  */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: -10px;         /*  compensate for item margin  */
}

.wrapper div {
  min-width: 300px;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;          /*  added left margin  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox is not really the best solution when gutters are important. It doesn't provide a natural method for creating gaps between items, without applying those gaps between items and the container. You would need to add general CSS and/or JS to make it work.

However, gutters are not a problem in [**CSS Grid Layout**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/), which provides specific properties for horizontal and vertical gaps:

- `row-gap`
- `column-gap`
- `gap` (the shorthand for both)

These properties create space between grid items, but not between items and the container.

> [**10.1. Gutters: the `row-gap`, `column-gap`, and
>   `gap`
>   properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters)
>
> The `row-gap` and `column-gap` properties (and their `gap` shorthand), when specified on a grid container, define the gutters between grid rows and grid columns.

**NOTE** that the CSS Grid spec was recently revised. These properties were previously listed as `grid-column-gap`, `grid-row-gap` and `grid-gap` ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#change-2016-grid-gap)).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper > div {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMbgvW?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a cleaner way to do it, but I guess this is sort of what you're looking for: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvbWyL

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background:black;
}

.columns__left {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.columns__right {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.container {
  max-width:700px;
  margin:20px auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div > div {
  min-width:300px;
  background:lightblue;
  border:1px solid blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding:10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 653px){
.columns__left {
   margin: 0;
  }
.columns__right {
  margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns__left">one</div>
  <div class="columns__right">two</div>
  <div class="columns__left">three</div>
  <div class="columns__right">four</div>
  <div>five</div>
</div>
```