# Setting margin only for outer borders of div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three columns inside a flex box container. I added margins around them, but I want to have only one margin applied for the inner borders. I suppose it is possible using :before and :after, but I am a novice :)

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.col {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
  width: 330%;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col">Need gutters? You could add margins to the columns. You could add padding to the columns. I like the idea of using justification to create the columns, like:<button>Procitaj ...</button></div>
  <div class="col">Need gutters? You could add margins to the columns. You could add padding to the columns. I like the idea of using justification to create the columns, like:
    <br/><button>Procitaj ...</button></div>
  <div class="col">Need gutters? You could add margins to the columns. You could add padding to the columns. I like the idea of using justification to create the columns, like:<button>Procitaj ...</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on: "I added padding around them, but I want to have only one padding applied for the inner borders." I think it might be doable using nth-child()

Comment: Sorry, I edited. The value of the margin on the 1st and last is 50px on the outer part, but between 1st and 2nd I want to have only 50px and not 100px (2x50px of margin for two elements). In that case al space around would be even

Comment: by inner borders you mean the space between each two columns? <col><space><col><space><col>?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48529808/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `:nth-child(2)` selector, You can target the 2 column al remove those 50px of margin.

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.col {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
  width: 330%;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px none;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 50px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="col">Need gutters? You could add margins to the columns. You could add padding to the columns. I like the idea of using justification to create the columns, like:<button>Procitaj ...</button></div>
  <div class="col">Need gutters? You could add margins to the columns. You could add padding to the columns. I like the idea of using justification to create the columns, like:
    <br/><button>Procitaj ...</button></div>
  <div class="col">Need gutters? You could add margins to the columns. You could add padding to the columns. I like the idea of using justification to create the columns, like:<button>Procitaj ...</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @HomeMade This might be what you are expecting. If not, please comment a little more on the problem.

Comment: thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

pad the container for most left and most right to be bigger.

make the margin on the col's smaller so the space between them is small.

| padding [] margin [] margin [] padding |